# Change colour of all elements expect the hovered element using CSS

Tags: html, css, onhover

I am creating a list using HTML and CSS. What I am trying to achieve is all the elements will be black until they are hovered on. When hovered, all elements except the hovered text will change color. I am attaching my code; it would be helpful if anyone could point out the mistake or tell me why it's not working.

```css
.sub-menu-mast {
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(254, 254, 254);
  width: 9rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sub-menu-mast>li>a {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
}

.sub-menu-mast a:not(:hover) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>XYZ </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu-mast">
        <li><a href="">Track</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Return</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, if I understood your request. Do you mean something like this?

```css
.sub-menu-mast {
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(254, 254, 254);
  width: 9rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav,
.menu,
.sub-menu-mast {
  outline: 1px dashed teal;
}

.sub-menu-mast>li>a {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
}

.sub-menu-mast li a {
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}

.sub-menu-mast:hover a:not(a:hover) {
  color: red;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.my-nav {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  outline: 1px dashed teal;
}

.my-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.my-nav li {
  width: 100%;
}

.my-nav a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.my-sub-menu li a {
  padding-left: 2em;
}

.my-nav li:hover,
.my-sub-menu li:hover {
  background: wheat;
}


/* either this ... */

.my-sub-menu:hover li a:not(:hover) {
  color: red;
}


/* ... or that */


/*
.my-sub-menu:hover li a {
  color: red;
}

.my-sub-menu:hover li a:hover {
  color: black;
}*/
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a>XYZ </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu-mast">
        <li><a href="">Track</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Return</a></li>
        <li><a href="">More</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Fixed</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="my-nav">
  <ul class="my-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
    <ul class="my-sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. This is how I wanted it. But there is a problem with this. When moving the cursor to hover, there is a period where all the text becomes red. It can be seen in your code too. Any idea how to remove this?

Comment: @ThorThedog I've added another example. If there is something funny going on with the blending it probably has to do with the element's boundaries. You can make sure that the hitbox/area is set up in a nice way. Make sure it does not lose focus while hovering (this may happen when the box is too tight). There is also `pointer-events: none` but this should be the last resort. Since `:has, :not, :is` etc. are relatively new and prone to errors/bugs, try with just overriding the previous selector as we did before in CSS (see comments in my example)

Comment: @ThorThedog Make sure that you account for borders, paddings, etc. as well. If for example you try to apply hover on `a` and parent `li` has a border, it will lose focus when you hover the border-line because the border is not part of that element. And if the transition is too harsh anyway consider using css `transition` to make it more smooth.